# How to get String value of item clicked in listview in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my database query and SimpleCursorAdapter setup:

```
db = stockDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

            final Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, name FROM types", null);

            SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    cursor,
                    new String[] { StockDatabaseContract.StockType.COLUMN_NAME_NAME },
                    new int[] { android.R.id.text1 },
                    0);
            lvTypes.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Here is the on click code:

```
 AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TypeSelection.this, BrandSelection.class);

                String selectedType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                intent.putExtra(BrandSelection.TYPE_NAME, selectedType);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
```

I only seem to get a value such as android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@435b9ba0
but need just the value of the item in the list like Vodka or Whiskey

Comment: You need to ensure you are binding String property with the list. If you are binding object then  String selectedType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position); will return the whole String object. So ensure what you are binding with listview.

Comment: @bluetoothfx can you explain what you mean by ensuring I am binding the String property with the list ?

Comment: if you bind String then 'getItemAtPosition' should return String not a Cursor object. Please try below solution, I hope you will find your result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your onclick listener:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
String drinkString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(" *column name* "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new 
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TypeSelection.this, BrandSelection.class);

               String selectedType = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).getDrinksName.toString();

                intent.putExtra(BrandSelection.TYPE_NAME, selectedType);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
```

Try using like this -

```
getItemAtPosition(position).getDrinksName.toString()
```

Comment: I don't think I can get the drinks name from the getItemAtPosition method as it seems to be getting a cursor object

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
// Index for name column is 1
String selectedType = cursor.getString(1);
```